# data parsing not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried to parse my JSON data to angular js app but parsing is not working on my wamp server. 
When I click the submit button on login page, there is no response. Please advise where I made mistake in my code.

**Controller.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("empApp", []);
app.controller("emp", ['$scope', 'empService', function($scope, empService){
  $scope.doSearch = function(){
    empService.findEmployeeById($scope.searchEmpno, function(r){
      $scope.empno = r.empno;
      $scope.ename = r.ename;
      $scope.edept = r.edept;
      $scope.esal = r.esal;
    });
  };
}]);

app.service("empService", ['$http', '$log', function($http, $log){
    this.findEmployeeById = function(empno, cb){
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost/',
            method: 'GET'
        })
      .then(function(resp){
          cb(resp.data);
        }, function(resp){
          $log.error('Error occurred');
        });
    };
  }
}]);

app.directive('empDetails', function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: 'emp-details.html'
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <body ng-app="empApp">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ng-controller="emp">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Enter Employee No:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="searchEmpno"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doSearch()">Click</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <div emp-details ng-if="empno != undefined">    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

**emp-details.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Employee details</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><strong>Employee No</strong></div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">{{empno}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><strong>Name:</strong></div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">{{ename}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><strong>Department:</strong></div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">{{edept}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSON:**

```
{
"employee":{ "empno": 251, "name":"John", "age":30, "edept":"New York" }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the folder `structure` of your project? Are you using a server for your project?  
@Muhammad is right, your URL is not defined properly. By knowing your folder structure, I will be able to provide more help.

Comment: All files have placed in the same location. I find the file on my browser the following URL: http://localhost/login.html

C:\wamp\www
controller.js
data.json
emp-details.html
login.html

Comment: Check out my answer. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @AllJs, it's not working...

Comment: I just edited the code. Take a look at it and let me know.  
Couple things. You didn't call the Service in your controller properly (You should always use the `then(...)` callback, once your `$http` is completed.  
Another thing is you don't need a cb in your Service definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Most of the issues are related to project structure and file organization.

I would recommend reading [johnpapa-angular-styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) for properly organizing and coding an angularJS application.

There are multiple changes needed.

- You're not referencing your `Controller.js` file.
- There is an additional `}` is there in your service
- There is no file like data.json. You will need to create that file and reference it in your service.
  `$http({
      url: 'data.json',
      method: 'GET'
  })`
- In your service you are returning `resp.data`. It should be `resp.data.employee`.

  `cb(resp.data.employee);`

> When you are referencing paths you should use [relative URL](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp).

See the working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ba1afoSNDjIRGnY52Dk3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of this:

- Change your URL from `'http://localhost/'` to `'data.json'`
- In the callback, change `resp.data` to `resp.data.employee`. This will make sure you directly get access to the employee data.

Let me know if this helps.

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.doSearch = function(employeeN){
    empService.findEmployeeById(employeeN)
    .then(function(r){
       $scope.empno = r.empno;
       $scope.ename = r.ename;
       $scope.edept = r.edept;
       $scope.esal = r.esal;
    });
};
```

**Service**

```
this.findEmployeeById = function(empno){
    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost/data.json',
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(function(resp){
      return resp.data.employee;
    }, function(resp){
      $log.error('Error occurred');
    });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doSearch(searchEmpno)">Click</button>
</div>
```